# std::exception occur on global thread object when calling exit in signal handler

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception

I got the following error when pressing `ctrl+c`

```
^Cctrl-c
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And here's gdb stackstrace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003a47432625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003a47433e05 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003a4a46007d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x0000003a4a45e0e6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#4  0x0000003a4a45e131 in std::terminate () at ../../.././libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
#5  0x000000000040172f in std::thread::~thread() ()
#6  0x00000000004036ad in void std::_Destroy<std::thread>(std::thread*) ()
#7  0x0000000000403396 in void std::_Destroy_aux<false>::__destroy<std::thread*>(std::thread*, std::thread*) ()
#8  0x000000000040311c in void std::_Destroy<std::thread*>(std::thread*, std::thread*) ()
#9  0x0000000000402dd6 in void std::_Destroy<std::thread*, std::thread>(std::thread*, std::thread*, std::allocator<std::thread>&) ()
#10 0x000000000040415b in std::vector<std::thread, std::allocator<std::thread> >::~vector() ()
#11 0x0000003a47435b22 in exit () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#12 0x000000000040142b in f(int) ()
#13 <signal handler called>
#14 0x0000003a478082fb in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#15 0x0000003a4a4bb627 in __gthread_join (__value_ptr=0x0, __threadid=<optimized out>)
    at /root/tmp/gcc-4.9.3/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/gthr-default.h:668
#16 std::thread::join (this=<optimized out>) at ../../../.././libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:107
#17 0x0000000000401540 in t2() ()
#18 0x0000000000401585 in main ()
```

And here's code:

```
vector<thread*> v1;
vector<thread> v2;

void task1(std::string msg){
    while (1) {
      cout << "task1 says: " << msg << endl;
      sleep(2);
    }
}

void ctrl_c(int s)
{
    cout << "ctrl-c\n";
    exit(0);
}

void func1()
{
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      v1.push_back(new thread(task1, "v1"));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        v1[i]->join();
    }
}

void func2()
{
#ifndef GLOBAL
    vector<thread> v2;
#endif
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      v2.push_back(thread(task1, "bad global v2"));
    }
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        v2[i].join();
    }
}



int main() { 
    signal(SIGINT,ctrl_c);
    //func1();
    //func2();
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that v1 is global vector,which contains thread pointer; v2 is global vector,which contains thread object

When I only run func1, program is ok;

When I only run func2, things will be different depending on whether the GLOBAL option is given on the command line. When given, program ok, when not given, above exception will occur. Furthermore, if I comment out `signal(SIGINT,ctrl_c)`, ctrl+c will not cause exception.(So I guess `exit` call causes global vector object destruction, right ?)

So my question is: what the differences among these conditions ? In the `func2` condition, if I want to capture SIGINT and call `exit` in its signal handler, at the same time I want to use global `vector<thread>`, how shoud I avoid the exception when pressing ctrl+c ?

**Thanks**

---

Comment: Yes, `exit()` calls destructors of global objects. `~std::thread()` destructor calls `terminate()` if the thread being destroyed has not been previously joined or detached. This is what you observe.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but why does the stack trace stopp at `pthread_join`, since it's not joined?

Comment: @scottxiao Three threads are created; all three run an infinite loop. `join` is called on the first, but since the thread doesn't terminate, that call waits forever. While that `join` is blocked (inside `pthread_join` apparently, but that's an internal implementation detail), the user presses Ctrl+C, which runs the signal handler, which calls `exit()`, which destroys global variables - including the other two `thread` objects that did not have `join` called on them.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik is signal handler called on random thread of process in linux? If so, the stacktrace may seem different everytime.

Comment: @scottxiao No idea. I'm a Windows guy myself. In Windows it's called on a separate thread in the same process. The stack trace shown in the question seems to suggest that the signal runs on the main thread - the same thread that called `join` - but like I said, I don't really know what I'm talking about; at least, not at the implementation level.

Answer (score 1):

Look at items 12-14 in your backtrace. You are inside `pthread_join()` (#12) when the signal is received (#13) and context switches to your signal handler (#14). You then call `exit(0)` from the signal handler context but the outer context *is still in* `pthread_join()`.

Suppose, for example, that `pthread_join()` has taken a lock on the thread object and the call to `thread::~thread()` attempts to take a lock on the same thread object. `thread::~thread()` is waiting in the signal handler context to take a lock that's being held in the outer context ... and the outer context cannot possibly release the lock until execution returns from the signal handler... and you have a resource deadlock.

That isn't what's happening here (the exact problem is as your first commenter says; terminate() is called on a thread which hasn't been first detached or joined). However, it's a very common scenario and tells the story of why you simply need to be careful when you mix signal handling and threads.

Begin with the assumption that you *shouldn't* *do* *anything* from within a signal handler and then make deliberate choices from there. Look in the man page for signal (`man 7 signal`) and you'll find a list of safe functions that can be called in a signal handler. You'll notice that `_exit()` is listed but `exit()` is not. I'll leave it to you to read the man pages to determine the major differences between `_exit()` and `exit()` (an obvious difference is very relevant here).

So, instead of explaining further the various reasons why your bad code misbehaves ... I'm just going to recommend a more appropriate use of your signal handler.

Generally, I recommend you only ever use a signal handler to set the value of a global flag variable. Outside of the signal handler context, you can check the value of the flag variable periodically to determine if a signal has been received. You can then act on the signal in the outer context and not in the signal handler context.

For example (only a code snippet, insert into your code reasonably):

```
static volatile int sigterm_caught = 0;

void task1(std::string msg){
    while (sigterm_caught == 0) {
      cout << "task1 says: " << msg << endl;
      sleep(2);
    }
}

void ctrl_c(int s)
{
  if(s == SIGTERM)
    sigterm_caught = 1;
}
```

Also note that `sleep(2)` will return prematurely after a signal has been received. So once your signal handler has set `sigterm_caught = 1` and returned, the `while(!sigterm_caught)` condition will be immediately evaluated in all your threads and your code will soon exit normally by `return 0` in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Shouldn't have used exit in signal handler